# java EE Hibernate List many to many configure error

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jsp, jakarta-ee

I am making a java ee web application. I have User and Permission classes and User class have List that types of Permission. When hibernate gets user object form database, i want to get permissions of user from user_permission table ,too.  User and Permission has many-to-many relation. I am using Hibernate 5.4.1 . When SessionFactory configurating i get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.hbm.ModelBinder$AbstractPluralAttributeSecondPass.bindCollectionElement(ModelBinder.java:3557)
    org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.hbm.ModelBinder$AbstractPluralAttributeSecondPass.doSecondPass(ModelBinder.java:3136)
    org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1684)
    org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1652)
    org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:286)
    org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:473)
    org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:84)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:689)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
```

my User class:

```
public class User
{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private List<Permission> permissions;
    public User(){}
    public User(String name,String password)
    {
        this.name=name;
        this.password=password;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name=name;
    }
    public String getPassword()
    {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password)
    {
        this.password=password;
    }
    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id=id;
    }
    public void clearPermissions()
    {
        permissions.clear();
    }
    public boolean hasPermission(Permission permission)
    {
        return permissions.contains(permission);
    }
    public void addPermission(Permission permission)
    {
        permissions.add(permission);
    }
    public void deletePermission(Permission permission)
    {
        permissions.remove(permission);
    }
    public List<Permission> getPermissions()
    {
        return permissions;
    }
    public void setPermissions(List<Permission> permissions)
    {
        this.permissions = permissions;
    }
}
```

user class mapping :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="model.User" table="user">
        <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>
        <property name="name" column="name" type="string"/>
        <property name="password" column="password" type="string"/>
        <list name="permissions" table="user_permission" lazy="false">
            <key column="user_id"/>
            <index column="id"/>
            <many-to-many class="Permission" column="permission_id"/>
        </list>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

my Permission class:

```
public class Permission
{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    public Permission() {}
    public Permission(int id, String name)
    {
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name=name;
    }
    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id=id;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        return ((Permission)obj).id==id;
    }
}
```

Permission class mapping :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="model.Permission" table="permission">
        <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>
        <property name="name" column="name" type="string"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: it should be one to many not many to many

Comment: But in the database user and permission tables are many to many. Cause a permisson can given to many users and an user can have many permissions.

Comment: in a many to many relationship, we get a 3rd table where is it defined?

Comment: Third table name is 'user_permission' . This table has 3 columns: id,user_id,permission_id

Comment: in the many to many tag the class=Permission, change it to model.Permission

Comment: Oh thank you it solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a missing packageName in many to many mapping. Change it from Permission to model.Permission. It should solve the problem. Below is the sippet

> ```
> <class name="model.User" table="user">
>     <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
>         <generator class="identity"/>
>     </id>
>     <property name="name" column="name" type="string"/>
>     <property name="password" column="password" type="string"/>
>     <list name="permissions" table="user_permission" lazy="false">
>         <key column="user_id"/>
>         <index column="id"/>
>         <many-to-many class="model.Permission" column="permission_id"/>
>     </list>
> </class> </hibernate-mapping>
> ```